# Pass host machine's environment variables to dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 5000
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/.urandom -jar /app.jar"]
```

I would like to pass a couple of environment variables like RDS_HOSTNAME to the docker container. How should I modify this file to do that?

Comment: `docker run -ti -e RDS_HOSTNAME=$RDS_HOSTNAME yourimage:latest`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass ENV during

- Build Time
- Run Time

To Set ENV during **build time** you will need modification in Dockerfile.

```
ARG RDS_HOSTNAME
ENV RDS_HOSTNAME="${RDS_HOSTNAME}"
```

And pass the `RDS_HOSTNAME` ENV during build time.

```
docker build --build-arg RDS_HOSTNAME=$RDS_HOSTNAME -t my_image .
```

Run Time:

As mentioned in the comment you can just pass

```
docker run -ti -e RDS_HOSTNAME=$RDS_HOSTNAME yourimage:latest
```

With the second approach, your Docker container will not container information if someone gets access but you will need to pass every time you run the container, while you first you just need to pass once during build time.